# Plotando evolução dos dados no tempo no R

Tags: r, lubridate

Boa tarde,

Estou com dificuldades em plotar essa série de dados ao longo do tempo. Eu gostaria de enxergar a frequencia de clientes sem CPF e sem nota por mês, e como esses indicadores estão evoluindo.

Eu consigo enxergar isso olhando todos os dados, da seguinte forma. Porém, tive outra dificuldade que foi a de agregar o campo NR_NR que é o numero de nota.

```
freq_cpf_nota <- orcamento_filtrado %>%
  group_by(TEM_CPF, TEM_NF) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(FREQUENCIA = (n / 48952 * 100)) %>% 
  ungroup()

structure(list(NR_ORCAMENTO = c("10182", "10182", "10182", "10225", 
"10225", "10225", "10225", "10226", "10226", "10227", "10228", 
"10229", "10229", "10229", "10229", "10230", "10231", "10231", 
"10232", "10233"), DT_EMISSAO = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), CICCGC = c("1457", "1457", "1457", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "1315", "1315", "3588", "2048", "5408", "5408", 
"5408", "5408", "1363", "1374", "1374", "226", NA), NM_CLIENTE = c("CRISTIANO SANTOS DO CARMO", 
"CRISTIANO SANTOS DO CARMO", "CRISTIANO SANTOS DO CARMO", "PAULO", 
"PAULO", "PAULO", "PAULO", "SIDNEY DE ABREU JUNIOR", "SIDNEY DE ABREU JUNIOR", 
"ARI PEREIRA DE REZENDE", "FABIANO ALVES DA SILVA", "MAESTRO LOCADORA DE VEIC LTDA", 
"MAESTRO LOCADORA DE VEIC LTDA", "MAESTRO LOCADORA DE VEIC LTDA", 
"MAESTRO LOCADORA DE VEIC LTDA", "ROSALINA CRISTINA S PEREIRA", 
"DANIEL ROSSONY FILHO", "DANIEL ROSSONY FILHO", "MARIA DO CARMO G DA S FARIA", 
"JORGE"), FONE_NUMERO = c("31025016", "31025016", "31025016", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "27928169", "27928169", "37788926", "1", 
"47850200", "47850200", "47850200", "47850200", "33711518", "1", 
"1", "31698881", "31844750"), PLACA = c("2767", "2767", "2767", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2589", "437", "437", "437", "437", 
"3321", "1103", "1103", "3815", NA), NR_NOTA = c("25336", "25336", 
"25336", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "28979", NA, "28986", "28986", 
"28986", "28986", "25337", "28980", "28980", "399", NA), TEM_CPF = c("Com CPF", 
"Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Sem CPF", "Sem CPF", "Sem CPF", "Sem CPF", 
"Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", 
"Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", "Com CPF", 
"Sem CPF"), TEM_NF = c("Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Sem Nota", 
"Sem Nota", "Sem Nota", "Sem Nota", "Sem Nota", "Sem Nota", "Com Nota", 
"Sem Nota", "Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Com Nota", 
"Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Com Nota", "Sem Nota"), TEM_PLACA = c("Com Placa", 
"Com Placa", "Com Placa", "Sem Placa", "Sem Placa", "Sem Placa", 
"Sem Placa", "Sem Placa", "Sem Placa", "Sem Placa", "Com Placa", 
"Com Placa", "Com Placa", "Com Placa", "Com Placa", "Com Placa", 
"Com Placa", "Com Placa", "Com Placa", "Sem Placa"), TEM_FONE = c("Com Telefone", 
"Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", 
"Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", 
"Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", 
"Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", 
"Com Telefone", "Com Telefone", "Com Telefone"), TEM_NOME = c("Com Nome", 
"Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", 
"Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", 
"Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", "Com Nome", 
"Com Nome"), DATA_MES = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("NR_ORCAMENTO", "DT_EMISSAO", 
"CICCGC", "NM_CLIENTE", "FONE_NUMERO", "PLACA", "NR_NOTA", "TEM_CPF", 
"TEM_NF", "TEM_PLACA", "TEM_FONE", "TEM_NOME", "DATA_MES"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Pode por favor editar a pergunta com a saída de `dput(orcamento_filtrado)` ou se a base for muito grande, `dput(head(orcamento_filtrado, 20))`? O problema com os dados assim é que vai ser difícil ler colunas com espaços nos seus valores.

Comment: eu tentei fazer isso, mas por algum motivo um dos campos ele não está dando head, e ta pegando a base toda, mesmo parametrizando o número de registros. sabe pq pode estar acontecendo isso?

Comment: Não, não podemos saber sem ver. Tente `sapply(orcamento_filtrado, class)` para ver se alguma coluna é um objeto de classe `list` ou mais esquisito. Pode também tentar `dput(orcamento_filtrado[1:20, ])`.

Comment: não funcionou tbm.. deu a mesma coisa.. o estranho eh que as classes são todas factor, dttm, chr, e dbl. e o dataset ta no formato data.frame... tentei converter para tibble mas nao resolveu tbm.. nao consigo enviar um csv?

Comment: Se deu tudo `factor` então está explicado, o resultado do `dput` é muito grande porque está a dar todos os níveis de cada fator. Volte a ler o ficheiro mas desta vez com o argumento `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` e deve resolver o problema do `dput`.

Comment: pronto! o problema era com o factor mesmo. converti para caracter e deu certo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso:

```
#aumentar os dados para mais meses:
orcamento_filtrado<-rbind(orcamento_filtrado,orcamento_filtrado)
orcamento_filtrado<-rbind(orcamento_filtrado,orcamento_filtrado)
orcamento_filtrado[20:40,13]=2
orcamento_filtrado[40:60,13]=3
orcamento_filtrado[60:80,13]=4

#filtro por características e mês:

freq_cpf_nota <- orcamento_filtrado %>%
  group_by(TEM_CPF, TEM_NF,DATA_MES) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(FREQUENCIA = (n / 48952 * 100)) %>% 
  ungroup()
freq_cpf_nota$TEMCPF_e_NF<-factor(paste(freq_cpf_nota$TEM_CPF,freq_cpf_nota$TEM_NF,sep=" e "))

plot(freq_cpf_nota$n~freq_cpf_nota$DATA_MES,col=freq_cpf_nota$TEMCPF_e_NF,pch=2)
legend("center",legend = levels(freq_cpf_nota$TEMCPF_e_NF),col=1:length(levels(freq_cpf_nota$TEMCPF_e_NF)),pch = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com ggplot

```
ggplot(aes(DATA_MES, n, group = TEMCPF_e_NF), data = freq_cpf_nota) +  
  geom_point(shape=23,size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=TEMCPF_e_NF), linetype=2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui deu o seguinte erro:

Error in plot.window(...) : valores finitos são necessários para 'xlim'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Em todo caso, o que eu preciso que apareça no eixo X são as datas. Eu tenho cerca de um ano e meio de dados, e gostaria de ver a evolução mês a mês de quantos orçamentos tem CPF, e quantos tem NF

Comment: Testa se funciona nos dados que vc postou ampliados

Comment: consegui fazer aqui.. mas o gráfico ficou bem ruim, a legenda está sobre o gráfico.. como poderia fazer um gráfico melhor? talvez com linhas ao invés de pontos

Comment: com ggplot talvez? não entendi muito bem a lógica que voce usou para conseguir levar para o ggplot

Comment: deu certo, obrigado!